# Operational problem to connect Postgres db

Tags: django, postgresql, database-migration

When trying to migrate, I receive the below error message. This means that my project cannot connect to my local PostgreSQL.

My project is on django. I work with Windows 11.

I googled and nearly all similar errors where linked somehow to Docker and docker-compose. While the current project isn't dockerized. I previously run a similar docker project through docker desktop, with postgres database.

While I don't know if that is relevant to my problem, I note in case it's relevant.

I also removed all docker container, images, volumes that could conflict with the current file, just in case.

I updated PostgreSQL and restart its settings.

Any return would be highly appreciated.

settings/base.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db_user',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_db_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

command:

```
python manage.py migrate:
```

error message:

```html
   (venv) C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\src>python manage.py migrate
C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\wagtail_meta_preview\wagtail_hooks.py:4: RemovedInWagtail50Warning: Importing from wagtail.core.hooks is deprecated. Use wagtail.hooks instead. See https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/3.0.html#changes-to-module-paths
  from wagtail.core import hooks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection        
self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 263, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection 
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\src\manage.py", line 43, in <module>
main()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\src\manage.py", line 39, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 114, in handle        
executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations       
if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 323, in cursor
return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 299, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection        
self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection        
self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 263, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection 
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError

(venv) C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\src>python manage.pya migrate
C:\Users\anica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\anica\PycharmProjects\digitalocean-deploy-tests\wagtail-pipit-scratch12\src\manage.pya': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: 1) Django version? 2) Pretty sure this `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` should be `django.db.backends.postgresql`. Per [3.0 deprecation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-3-0): *The django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 module will be removed.*.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver per the dperecation note. Django version : 4.1. I changed the engine's value, yet  the same error message persists also with  `django.db.backends.postgresql` .

Comment: 1) Is there more content in the traceback then you are showing? 2) Have you looked at the Postgres log to see if there is more information? 3) From here [Django 4.1 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/) Python 3.11 is supported from Django 4.1.3+. Are you at 4.1.3 or above?  **ADD information as update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, my python version on the ubuntu server is 3.10, django version is 4.1.7.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, per your request, I added the entire log.

Comment: 1) You did not follow the previous request, **ADD information as update to question.** 2) The new  traceback is for an entirely different environment. Explain why you changed it, as update to question. 3) You have not indicated whether you looked at Postgres logs and whether they had useful information.